# pytest reuse fixture between projects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

I want to create fixtures as library components.

A standard test database config is useful for several projects in different repos. It is currently copy/pasted into each independent project as they can't share a config.py.

I refactored the code into a pip installable library but can't work out an elegant way to use it in each project. This doesn't work:

```py
import my_db_fixture

@pytest.fixture
def adapted_db_fixture(my_db_fixture):
    # adapt the test setup
```

For the real code, the fixture I want to re-use is built from other fixtures. The best work-around I can find so far is to create a local conftest.py as copy/paste code but limited to importing functions and calling them in local fixture functions. I don't like copy/paste and unnecessarily exposes the inner workings of the fixtures.

Comment: If there isn't an elegant solution, tell me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to re-use fixtures from an installed library.

Define the fixtures as usual in the installable package. Then import them into a  conftest.py local to the project. You need to import not just the fixture you want but also all fixtures it depends on and (if used) pytest_addoption

```py
from my.package import (
    the_fixture_i_want,
    all_fixtures_it_uses,
    pytest_addopt
)
```

I also discovered you can't un-decorate a library function with a teardown and call it in the local conftest.py:

```py
# This doesn't work

# pip installed my_fixture.py
def my_fixture(dependencies)
    # setup code
    yield fixture_object
    # teardown code

# local conftest.py
import pytest
import my_fixture  # NB: the module

@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture(dependencies):
    my_fixture.my_fixture()
    # teardown code isn't called: pytest knows the function has no yield
    # but doesn't realise it's returning a generator none the less
```

This article helped me:

[peterhurford/pytest-fixture-modularization.md](https://gist.github.com/peterhurford/09f7dcda0ab04b95c026c60fa49c2a68)

I reckoned pytest should recognise something returning a generator as a generator so logged it as a bug. I imagine comments responding to it could be useful:

[call_fixture_func should test the return value not the function](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/7235)

Comment: I believe I'm recommending an improper way to solve the problem. The official way to re-use fixtures between projects seems to be plugins https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html. I don't really understand why this more complicated approach is better.